# Pandas: universal columns attribute for DataFrame and Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributes, series

I have a function that gets passed a DataFrame and uses the df.columns attribute.  However, this breaks when it's passed a DataFrame that has only one column (series), because a series doesn't have that attribute.

Is there an attribute that would work for both a series and a dataframe that would be equivalent to df.columns for a DataFrame ? I've looked, but given that the columns attribute is not even shown in the DataFrame documentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), I thought there might be a solution out there in the form of some tribal knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

use `.name` for a series, I'd just test the `type` of the object being passed and call `.columns` or `.name` as appropriate:

```
In [242]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[242]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []

In [243]:
df['a'].name

Out[243]:
'a'
```

Like this:

```
In [245]:
def func(x):
    if type(x) is pd.DataFrame:
        print( x.columns)
    elif type(x) is pd.Series:
        print( x.name)

print(func(df))
print(func(df['a']))

Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
None
a
None
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it requires 2+2n lines of code compared to the the n lines I currently have.  Is there really no other solution?

Comment: not really, there isn't a common attribute here as they're fundamentally different types, it's possible to pass a single column df by doing `df[['a']]` this would pass a single column df